# Setup Script throws Error : Call to undefined method Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::addAttribute()

Tags: magento-1.9, setup-script

I am following a tutorial from the book of Roman Zenner & Vinai Kopp called "Magento - The Handbook for Developers" (german: Magento - Das Handbuch für Entwickler).

Snippet from **config.xml**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <WR_EPO>
            <version>1.0.0.12</version>
        </WR_EPO>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <wr_epo_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>WR_EPO</module>
                </setup>
            </wr_epo_setup>
            ...
```

It says that I need this setup script:
The script is in (app/code/local/WR/EPO/sql/wr_epo_setup/upgrade-1.0.0.11-1.0.0.12):

```
<?php
/**
 * @var Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup $installer
 */

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

Mage::Log("Setup Script is getting executed.", 7, "setup.log");

$installer->addAttribute('quote_item', 'shipping_surcharge', array(
        'label' => 'Versandkostenaufpreis'
        ,'type' => 'decimal'
    )
);

$installer->endSetup();
```

But I get a 500 Status Code Error and the error `Call to undefined method Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::addAttribute()` is getting logged.

---

I also tried this:

Snippet from **config.xml**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <WR_EPO>
            <version>1.0.0.12</version>
        </WR_EPO>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <wr_epo_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>WR_EPO</module>
                </setup>
            </wr_epo_setup>
            <wr_epo_sales_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>WR_EPO</module>
                    <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </wr_epo_sales_setup>
            ...
```

... and moved the setup script from `app/code/local/WR/EPO/sql/wr_epo_setup/upgrade-1.0.0.11-1.0.0.12` to `app/code/local/WR/EPO/sql/wr_epo_sales_setup/upgrade-1.0.0.11-1.0.0.12` but now the setup script is not getting executed at all, I already removed the entry in the core_resources table and reloaded the site.

Is the tutorial outdated? How to do it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue isn't with your setup script. You aren't using the proper setup resource in your `config.xml`.

You need to use the `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup` model, not the default setup model.

Example from Magento Sales module:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_Sales>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Mage_Sales>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <sales_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Mage_Sales</module>
                    <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </sales_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: I tried it with the class `<class>Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup</class>` but now my setup script is not getting executed at all.

Comment: My fault, I just copied the script from wr_epo_setup to wr_epo_sales_setup and none of them where executed because they are both doing the same. If I comment one of them out, then it works and the setup script log entry is created. Now I have to check if the attribute was really added. Thx!